# How to increase blast furnace top gas temperature?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, metallurgy

Why does blast furnace (in Iron & Steel works) top gas temperature stays low and what are the fixes for that to increase without using a burner?

The top gas temperature goes below 80 degrees (celcius) and the system requires a burner to increase the level of temp. Why we would need a burner, there should be a different way for not to decrease its temperatures.

Comment: How low is low? 20 degrees below or down at ambient?

Comment: Below 80 degrees (celcius) and around that...

Comment: Okay I am not familiar with blast furnaces but if I understand this correctly there may be a meaningful answer we can give with a mass & energy balance. First from what I see blast furnaces depend on the consumption of air, and at the top stages there seems not to be too much air or fuel left, pressure drops and we know that also causes a heat loss. Perhaps we can treat this as an absorber column with reaction, do you have any schematics for the particular unit operation you are using?

Comment: @Media What do you mean by absorber column with reaction?We can't share the schematics but I'm following some patents in order to improve top gas temp.: 1) https://patents.google.com/patent/CN108642219A/en?q=~patent%2fCN108642219A   2)  https://patents.google.com/patent/CN109385497A/en?q=~patent%2fCN109385497A 3) https://patents.google.com/patent/CN107119156A/en?q=~patent%2fCN107119156A  , what kind of reasons could cause this?